# View scrolls to top when the spinner valueis changed

Tags: android, spinner

I have all views in a `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="www.sample.com.Settings">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/basic_settings"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/settings_header_1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
.
.
.
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/job"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
 <Spinner
     android:background="@drawable/textbox"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/jobs">
 </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

When the value of the I change the value of the spinner the view scrolls to the top. but why? and how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was the emulator problem and there was no problem when testing on a real phone.